# Can I assign greater RAM to VirtualBox than Windows?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have Windows 7 in my laptop and I am using VirtualBox. I have 3 GB RAM.  I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 for learning purpose in VirtualBox and assigned 1 GB RAM but it seems very slow.

My question is Can I assign RAM more than Windows means 2 GB to VirtualBox (Ubuntu). Assigning RAM more to VirtualBox than Windows will cause any problem to my system or not ?

Comment: Are you sure that the RAM is culprit?

Comment: @LittleHelper I have enabled 3D Acceleration so I was thinking that it may be RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have 3GB of RAM on your machine, you could try to assign 2GB to VirtualBox. But then Windows 7 will be a bit choked as far as RAM goes and nothing will work well on the host side including VirtualBox.

If upgrading the RAM is not possible, but you have a multicore CPU I would recommend assigning an extra core to the VirtualBox guest OS install to see of that helps.

But when all is said and done if you choke the resources on the host system, the host system will not work well and the VirtualBox guest OS installs will not work well at all.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter as long as you have enough RAM. But assign too much memory to VirtualBox may slow down your host system.